# What makes a web application a touch pad friendly application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, touch

Designing a web application with ASP.NET MVC I asked myself how can I also please those people using a smart phone, ipad, etc.. (everything thats touchable...) and not only a desktop/notebook with a browser.

How can I develop a better user experience.

I would be pleased to hear about technical advises concerning the asp.net mvc framework so I can later implement your suggestions concretely.

Comment: If you are developing for a touch interface such as iPhone/iPad/Android, then make sure you do not include any code that makes you HOVER over something to see it/interact with it. These devices do not have the concept of hover. If you do this, then at least provide some sort of workaround.

Comment: This question might get better answers at the [User Experience Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @djacobson I will do that later too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through my tutorial [ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile Features](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features)

- create mobile-specific views.

-use the HTML5 viewport attribute and adaptive rendering to improve display on mobile devices.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few levels of friendlyness. You can start with the basic "does this site render well enough to be usable in a mobile browser?" This really should not be a problem for anything new that is using modern web standards but older sites could have problems. Corallary to this is "is my site a bandwidth hog that takes forever to render over 3g because each page is 14mb of animated GIFs and spaghetti HTML?" Or "does my site make mobile devices melt due to aggresive scripts?" Luckily this set is pretty easy to deal with -- modern websites tend to handle this pretty well by default.

The second level is "does this site do anything maddening from a touch perspective." The big thing that can clip you here is hover based menus -- there is **no** hover on a touch UI. The other common issue is using small links or buttons that one can't hit at least without zooming in to crazy levels. The solution here is testing -- some issues are obvious to all but you won't see some things until you are interacting without a mouse.

The final level is using a touch UI for fun and profit. If you make it this far, you are doing better than many web publishers in this day and age. What is involved here is using touch-friendly UI tools, such as jquery mobile, to handle swipe events and other touch features to make things work more like one expects with a touch UI. An easy example would be making an image carousel swipe-able rather than having to wait for the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Make the interface chunky - big icons are easy to click, text is very difficult to touch accurately. Set a minimum size for every element, at the very least as big as the individual keys on an iPhone/android's virtual keyboard and preferably much larger.

Ensure that the most relevant options are near the top, and after that the aim is simply to make it intuitive. Fewer menus are generally better.